# MySQL: foreign key constraint not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table, `companies_employers`, with one foreign key, `company_id`, which references `id` in `companies table`.

```
CREATE TABLE `companies_employers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `companies_employers_ibfk` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I populate `companies_employers` and then run:

```
SELECT * FROM companies_employers
```

`company_id` is empty.

Now I run:

```
SELECT company_id FROM `companies_employers`
```

Working, it gives the correct value.

Why can't I get it with `SELECT * FROM companies_employers`? Can someone explain this?

**UPDATE**

Screenshots from the scenarios:

[image: SELECT * FROM companies_employers]

[image: SELECT company_id FROM <code>companies_employers</code>]

[image: Update field]

Comment: It is highly unlikely that mysql would not return a field's value when you use *, but would return it when you use the field's name. Plus I fail to see how this is related to foreign keys. How exactly did you populate the field and what do you see when you run select * and what do you see when you select the particular field only? Pls attach screenshots!

Comment: I just did a simple INSERT INTO companies_employers (first_name, last_name, company_id) VALUES ('Peter', 'Sall', 3605); Check my update.

Comment: This is probably one of those few questions where phpmyadmin tag is valid. I think this is a display issue within phpmyadmin. Try to access the database through a different client and execute the select * from there.

Comment: I don't get this? I haven't done anything and now it's working on localhost? :D